Running ML agents executable not working in linux after project runs fine in windows
Hi I have been developing in windows and running ML Agents simulations without issue. I am now trying to switch to linux to run simulations with better efficiency.
My approach to do this is to download my project as a linux executable and run it in the linux shell that I have ssh’d into
Versions:
Python 3.8.10
ml-agents: 0.27.0,
ml-agents-envs: 0.27.0,
Communicator API: 1.5.0,
PyTorch: 1.8.1+cu102
Unity 2022.3.2f1, I also tried 2020.2.6f1 with no better results
Linux Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Process:
file->build settings->Windows, Mac, Linux->Linux->Development Build->Build and ssh to linux machine
Run: mlagents-learn config/ppoagent.yaml --env=visibility_game_linux_build2022.x86_64 --no-graphics --force
this Gives me the error
[INFO] Learning was interrupted. Please wait while the graph is generated.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/bin/mlagents-learn”, line 8, in
sys.exit(main())
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/learn.py”, line 250, in main
run_cli(parse_command_line())
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/learn.py”, line 246, in run_cli
run_training(run_seed, options)
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/learn.py”, line 125, in run_training
tc.start_learning(env_manager)
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents_envs/timers.py”, line 305, in wrapped
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/trainer_controller.py”, line 198, in start_learning
raise ex
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/trainer_controller.py”, line 173, in start_learning
self._reset_env(env_manager)
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents_envs/timers.py”, line 305, in wrapped
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/trainer_controller.py”, line 105, in _reset_env
env_manager.reset(config=new_config)
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/env_manager.py”, line 68, in reset
self.first_step_infos = self._reset_env(config)
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/subprocess_env_manager.py”, line 334, in _reset_env
ew.previous_step = EnvironmentStep(ew.recv().payload, ew.worker_id, {}, {})
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/subprocess_env_manager.py”, line 98, in recv
raise env_exception
mlagents_envs.exception.UnityEnvironmentException: Environment shut down with return code 1.

Additionally the python code:
from mlagents_envs.environment import UnityEnvironment
env = UnityEnvironment(file_name=‘visibility_game_linux_build2022.x86_64’)

Results in the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “”, line 1, in
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents_envs/environment.py”, line 223, in init
aca_output = self._send_academy_parameters(rl_init_parameters_in)
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents_envs/environment.py”, line 477, in _send_academy_parameters
return self._communicator.initialize(inputs, self._poll_process)
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents_envs/rpc_communicator.py”, line 121, in initialize
self.poll_for_timeout(poll_callback)
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents_envs/rpc_communicator.py”, line 108, in poll_for_timeout
poll_callback()
File “/home/rmarr/Documents/GflowsForSimulation_env/GflowsForSimulation_venv_real/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents_envs/environment.py”, line 403, in _poll_process
raise UnityEnvironmentException(exc_msg)
mlagents_envs.exception.UnityEnvironmentException: Environment shut down with return code 1.


Please extract a [mcve]. Also, run your code in a debugger. That said, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Point is, you're not even asking a question!
